# How to exit the Azure SQL script to skip all remaining batches?

Tags: azure-sql-database, error-handling

I have a Python script that glues together individual SQL scripts like: creating tables, creating views, creating functions, creating stored procedures... It produces the single installation SQL script.

Having more "similar" databases in one SQL server and using SSMS, I would like to avoid the user error by using the installation script for the unrelated database.

The Python script basically just concatenates the individual scripts in the correct order with the `GO` command after each one. Like this:

```
-- create_table_log.sql --------------------

IF (OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.log', 'U') IS NULL) BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.log (
        ts    datetime2 NOT NULL,
        user_ nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
        msg   nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
        code  int NOT NULL 
    )
END

GO
-------------------------------------------

-- usp_log.sql --------------------

IF (OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.usp_log', 'P') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.usp_log
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_log @msg nvarchar(MAX),
                             @code int = 0,
                             @user nvarchar(40) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF @user = ''
        SET @user = SYSTEM_USER

    INSERT dbo.log (ts, user_, msg, code)
    VALUES (SYSDATETIME(), @user, @msg, @code)
    PRINT @msg
END
```

My idea was to add the initial part that would check the name of the database and would exit the whole script early in the case. So, I have used:

```
DECLARE @expected_dbname nvarchar(50) = 'xxx_db'
DECLARE @this_dbname nvarchar(50) = DB_NAME()

IF @this_dbname <> @expected_dbname BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'Must be executed in the context of the ''%s'' database.', 0, 1, @expected_dbname) WITH NOWAIT
    RAISERROR(N'Was executed in the context of ''%s'' (early termination).', 11, 1, @this_dbname) WITH NOWAIT
    RETURN
END

GO
-------------------------------------------
```

The `RETURN` ends execution only of the current batch. However, I was expecting that `RAISERROR` with severity 11 (*Indicates that the given object or entity doesn't exist.*) will end the execution in the SSMS console. It did not.

**What is the correct way to stop execution immediately -- not executing even further batches in the same script?** As the batches (between `GO`) are executed kind of independently, it probably has to be the equivalent of the "cancel button" in the SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this while using `GO` batch separators in your script. They tell the script to move on to the next batch regardless of error state, even with XACT_ABORT set to true.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SELECT 
    x = 1/0
GO 
RAISERROR('a mostly sunny day, to some, can look a lot like partly grey', 20, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
GO 
SELECT 
    x = 1;
GO
```

You would have to change your script in a way where a different step runs first to check database name, then moves on to the object check/creation/whatever else you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

[SET NOEXEC ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-noexec-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) might work for you.

e.g.

```sql
DECLARE @expected_dbname nvarchar(50) = 'xxx_db'
DECLARE @this_dbname nvarchar(50) = DB_NAME()

IF @this_dbname <> @expected_dbname BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'Must be executed in the context of the ''%s'' database.', 0, 1, @expected_dbname) WITH NOWAIT
    RAISERROR(N'Was executed in the context of ''%s'' (early termination).', 11, 1, @this_dbname) WITH NOWAIT
    SET NOEXEC ON
    RETURN
END
GO
SELECT 'This shouldn''t run'
GO
SET NOEXEC OFF
```

[sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/edit-sqlcmd-scripts-query-editor?view=sql-server-ver16) mode might also be an option but it would require checking at the start of each batch.  It allows you to create a variable that spans the scope of the batch which isn't normally possible.

```
:setvar ExpectedDBName "tempdb"

GO
IF '$(ExpectedDBName)' <> DB_NAME()
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'Must be executed in the context of the ''%s'' database.', 0, 1, '$(ExpectedDBName)') WITH NOWAIT
    RAISERROR(N'Was executed in the context of ''%s'' (early termination).', 11, 1, '$(ExpectedDBName)') WITH NOWAIT
    RETURN
END
SELECT 'Test 1'
GO
```

Comment: It partially works. However, once it was `SET NOEXEC ON`, it seems to be set ON "forever". When I put `SET NOEXEC OFF` as the very first command, it seems to work. Anyway, the `NOEXEC` is ON until the `SET NOEXEC OFF` is executed. Any idea for improvement?

Comment: Yes NOEXEC would be ON until you run `SET NOEXEC OFF`.  I would put `SET NOEXEC OFF` at the end of the script like in the example so it will put things back as it was.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an alternative to use sqlcmd mode.  NOEXEC is probably a better option, but use what works best for your use case.  I've never needed to use NOEXEC myself, but I know Redgate uses it in the deployment scripts that SQL Compare generates.

Comment: For deployments, you might also consider using SSDT/dacpac.

Comment: If the script stops with the NOEXEC OFF, the the next run of the script should **start** with setting it ON again. Setting it ON at the end would not help for this (the second) run of the script.

Answer (score 0):

> Having more "similar" databases in one SQL server and using SSMS, I would like to avoid the user error by using the installation script for the unrelated database.

Why not just fully qualify each `CREATE` statement with the 3-part name that includes the database name? For example:

```
CREATE TABLE TheDatabaseName.dbo.log (
        ts    datetime2 NOT NULL,
        user_ nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
        msg   nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
        code  int NOT NULL 
    )
```

Comment: I possibly understand that you want to use the side effect. However, the same "snippet" (definition of the procedure) can be used in the other database. When implementing the other solution, I just create the specific database, and copy the subset of definitions that is needed for the solution. Also, in Azure SQL, `TheDatabaseName` makes sense only if it is equal to the current database. No `USE TheDatabaseName`, not 3-part identifiers to another database. +1 anyway.

Comment: @pepr "*However, the same "snippet" (definition of the procedure) can be used in the other database. When implementing the other solution, I just create the specific database, and copy the subset of definitions that is needed for the solution.*" - Do you know the names of which databases are allowed to run the script?...because unless they're static I don't think it's possible to do what you want.

Comment: @pepr "*Also, in Azure SQL, TheDatabaseName makes sense only if it is equal to the current database.*" - Sounds like this approach would still work in Azure then, since it'll either run the script successfully when the user runs it in the correct database, otherwise none of it will run (it'll error out).

Comment: The snippet that would be added as first into the installation script would definitely contain the database name (it is specific for the solution, for that exact subset of definitions glued together). Yes, your approach would work. But I would like to express "my assumption" only in the first element of the installation script.

Comment: @pepr Sorry I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: To explain... When sharing the set of procedures/definitions, I prefer to have them the same everywhere -- if they are used. This way, I can easily update the version everywhere (by copying the new version). The (sub)set of definitions is concatenated into the installation script in given order (by rules). So, I would like to solve it withing the snippet that forms the beginning of the installation script. So, I want to specialize only that first snippet for the target database.